Showing Non-English Characters from CLOB datatype when the length is > 32767
I am getting Non-English characters in my output.
string oradb = "User Id=XXX;Password=XXX; DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.10.10.10)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXX)));Pooling=false;Connection Timeout=60;";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DESCR, FOLLOW_UP_NOTES FROM CTL WHERE CTL_ID = 1010101062";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter dr = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
dr.Fill(ds);

Here DESCR is a CLOB datatype and FOLLOW_UP_NOTES is string. I am getting different language characters in FOLLOW_UP_NOTES when the length of DESCR is > 32767.
Screenshot from VS debug
I am expecting the FOLLOW_UP_NOTES to be displayed in English but it is displayed in non english language. The same FOLLOW_UP_NOTES is displaying correctly if DESCR is < 32767.

Apparently, that's what is in your database. What else would you expect? Which driver do you use?

Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

CLOBs have no 32K limitation, but other datatypes do (e.g. varchar2 and raw in PL/SQL). Some string functions when applied to LOBs also have similar limitations and can do strange things particularly in older versions. Then there's any number of similar possibilities outside of Oracle before the data was loaded.  So it probably is a conversion error earlier on when the data was loaded or further upstream. Your CLOB simply contains what was put in the table.
